# Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy not working at all

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I have asked a previous question regarding Bootstrap ScrollSpy and this is my final attempt at trying to get this to work.

What I am trying to achieve is to change the colour of the navbar a tag when scrolling in that section. I have tried many ways and even have a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richlewis14/NySg6/) working but even that setup in my app does not work

This is what I have

JS

```
$('#spyOnThis').scrollspy();
```

Body

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#spyOnThis">
```

View

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row show-grid clear-both">
  <div id="left-sidebar" class="span3 sidebar">
  <div class="side-nav sidebar-block">
    <h3 class="resultTitle fontSize13">Release Dates</h2>
    <ul class="date">
      <% @response.each_pair do |date, movie| %>
      <li><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i><%= link_to date_format(date), "#d_#{date}", :id=> '#d_#{date}' %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="span9">
  <div id="dateNav">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><% @response.each_pair do |date, movie| %><%= link_to date_format(date), "#d_#{date}" %><% end %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="spyOnThis">
  <% @response.each_pair do |date, movie| %>
    <h3 class="resultTitle fontSize13" id="d_<%= date %>">Available on&nbsp;<%= date_format(date) %></h3>
    <% movie.each do |m| %>
      <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
        <img class="pull-left" src=<% if m.image_link %> <%= m.image_link %> <% else %> "/assets/noimage.jpg" <% end %>>
        <div class="caption pull-right">
          <%= link_to m.name, m.title_id, :class => 'resultTitle fontSize11' %>
          <p class="bio"><%= m.bio %></p>
          <p class="resultTitle">Cast</p>
          <p class="bio"><%= m.cast.join(", ") unless m.cast.empty? %></p>
          <%= link_to "Remind me", reminders_path(:title_id => m.title_id), :method => :post, :class => 'links button' %>
        </div>
      </div>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div><!--span9-->
</div><!--Row-->
</div><!--/container-->
```

CSS

```
#dateNav{
position: fixed;
top: 0; left: 20px;
width: 100%;
background:none;
text-align:center;
}

#spyOnThis {
 height:100%;
 overflow:auto;
}

 .nav > li > a {
  display:block;
  }

.nav > li.active > a {
 display:block;
 color: red;
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

i know that height 100% may cause an issue but the height of my scroller will depend on the content and it can change.

I am now pulling my hair out, i have read that this scrollspy is quite buggy but surely it must work as the demo on their site does

EDIT

```
$('#dateNav').scrollspy();

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#dateNav">
```

HTML

```
ul class="nav">
 <li>
 <a href="#d_2013-01-09">9th Jan 2013</a>
 <a href="#d_2013-01-11">11th Jan 2013</a>
 <a href="#d_2013-01-18">18th Jan 2013</a>
 <a href="#d_2013-01-23">23rd Jan 2013</a>
 <a href="#d_2013-01-25">25th Jan 2013</a>
 <a href="#d_2013-01-30">30th Jan 2013</a>
 </li>
```

```
<div id="spyOnThis">
 <h3 id="d_2013-01-09" class="resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 9th Jan 2013</h3>
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <h3 id="d_2013-01-11" class="resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 11th Jan 2013</h3>
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <h3 id="d_2013-01-18" class="resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 18th Jan 2013</h3>
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <h3 id="d_2013-01-23" class="resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 23rd Jan 2013</h3>
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <h3 id="d_2013-01-25" class="resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 25th Jan 2013</h3>
 </div>
```

This turns all the links red so they are now all active?

also my body is 100% for sticky footer, not sure if that makes a difference
Help really appreciated

Comment: Should `id="d_<%= date %>"` from your `H3` tags be moved to `<% movie.each do |m| %>`
      `<div id="d_<%= date %>" class="thumbnail clearfix">`. I'm new to ScrollSpy myself, but I believe you're missing an id for the "boxes".

Comment: i dont think so because the h3 starts each section on movies in my case, so i want the h3 to be the trigger

Comment: Just verifying you have `dateNav` set in your body tag and not `navbar`. A copy of your output would be helpful as well.

Comment: i have made an update to my question, output? what would you like to see?

Comment: Thanks, just a html sample of your `<ul class="nav">` and `<div id="spyOnThis">`.

Comment: updated with output html for you

Comment: Hello again! Just a suggestion: put **all** of your outputted HTML (with updates from the answers), relevant CSS, and the `.scrollspy()` line of JS into a jsFiddle - it will make it much easier for answerers to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Hello Sara (hangs head in shame :) ) yes fiddles seem the way to go, few basic errors by myself mind haven't helped the situation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to move the data-spy and data-target attributes from the body:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#dateNav">
```

and move them to the div "spyOnThis":

```
<div id="spyOnThis">
```

Should be:

```
<div id="spyOnThis" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#dateNav">
```

Per the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy%3a):

"To easily add scrollspy behavior to your topbar navigation, just add data-spy="scroll" to the element you want to spy on (most typically this would be the body) and data-target=".navbar" to select which nav to use. You'll want to use scrollspy with a .nav component."

Based on your HTML you also need to fix a couple things:

Your list tags are not closed:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#d_2013-01-09">9th Jan 2013</a>
        <a href="#d_2013-01-11">11th Jan 2013</a>
        <a href="#d_2013-01-18">18th Jan 2013</a>
        <a href="#d_2013-01-23">23rd Jan 2013</a>
        <a href="#d_2013-01-25">25th Jan 2013</a>
        <a href="#d_2013-01-30">30th Jan 2013</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Should be:

```
<ul class="nav dateNav">
    <li><a href="#d_2013-01-09">9th Jan 2013</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d_2013-01-11">11th Jan 2013</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d_2013-01-18">18th Jan 2013</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d_2013-01-23">23rd Jan 2013</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d_2013-01-25">25th Jan 2013</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d_2013-01-30">30th Jan 2013</a></li>
</ul>
```

Your divs not properly closed either:

```
<div id="spyOnThis">
 <h3 id="d_2013-01-09" class="resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 9th Jan 2013</h3>
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <h3 id="d_2013-01-11" class="resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 11th Jan 2013</h3>
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <h3 id="d_2013-01-18" class="resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 18th Jan 2013</h3>
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
 <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
     <h3 id="d_2013-01-23" class="resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 23rd Jan 2013</h3>
     <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
     <h3 id="d_2013-01-25" class="resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 25th Jan 2013</h3>
 </div>
```

Should be (just showing a couple of them):

```
<div class="thumbnail clearfix">
     <h3 id="d_2013-01-23" class="resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 23rd Jan 2013</h3>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail clearfix">
     <h3 id="d_2013-01-25" class="resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 25th Jan 2013</h3>
</div>
```

Also it seems that the 100% height causes it to only highlight the bottom-most entry in the navbar list.

Comment: thank you for your answer, though now all dates are red so they are still all active?

Comment: Check the formatting of the list tags. The way you have them in your HTML as <li><a href="xyz"></a><a href="xyz1"></a></li> is just grouping them into one list item.

Instead set it up as <li><a href="xyz"></a></li>    <li><a href="xyz1"></a></li> and it should resolve that issue.

Comment: Here is a "working" JSFiddle, I used the CSS from your fiddle example and added your HTML into it so it is kind of a mash-up but gets the point across: http://jsfiddle.net/YqWQL/

If you set up the <li> structure similar to how your HTML is currently you will see all of the links turn red.

Comment: thanks very much, just fixed li issue working on divs now, at moment the last li is highlighted red so getting there, thanks very much for your help, well both of you really

Comment: You're welcome. The issue with the last item being highlighted all of the time is related to the height:100% in the #spyOnThis css. 

Here is some discussion: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5007

and another SO question related to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095579/twitter-bootstrap-scrollspy-always-selecting-last-element

Answer (score 2):

Alright, firstly your nav links should individually be wrapped in `li` tags i.e.

```
    <div id="dateNav">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#d_2013-01-09">9th Jan 2013</a></li>
        <li><a href="#d_2013-01-11">11th Jan 2013</a></li>
        <li><a href="#d_2013-01-18">18th Jan 2013</a></li>
        <li><a href="#d_2013-01-23">23rd Jan 2013</a></li>
        <li><a href="#d_2013-01-25">25th Jan 2013</a></li>
        <li><a href="#d_2013-01-30">30th Jan 2013</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Secondly your `<div id="spyOnThis">` div is missing a lot of closing div tags, so they're all nested instead of below each other. I simply removed your `<div class="thumbnail clearfix">` divides to leave the following:

```
    <div id="spyOnThis">
      <h3 id="d_2013-01-09" class="box resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 9th Jan 2013</h3>
      <h3 id="d_2013-01-11" class="box resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 11th Jan 2013</h3>
      <h3 id="d_2013-01-18" class="box resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 18th Jan 2013</h3>
      <h3 id="d_2013-01-23" class="box resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 23rd Jan 2013</h3>
      <h3 id="d_2013-01-25" class="box resultTitle fontSize13">Available on 25th Jan 2013</h3>
    </div>
```

You can add the divides back in, but make sure you close them or the ScrollSpy won't be able to track it properly and will just break.

Answer (score 1):

If you dive into the code for this plugin its actually very imporant that you select the parent to the .nav

```
this.selector = (this.options.target
      || ((href = $(element).attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) //strip for ie7
      || '') + ' .nav li > a'
```