# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Scrollsy ERRORs

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I have a Django Landing page + few extra description pages.

I store the navbar with bootstrap 4 scrollspy in the base.html file what points on IDs on the home.html.
When I am on the home page it works like in the official bootstarp [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#example-in-navbar).

**1.ERROR**

But when I go to other pages it just puts this URL out "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/services/#pricing" and stay under the "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/services/" URL.

I get a terminal ERROR message as well:

```
Not Found: /docs/4.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
[13/Jan/2020 16:16:35] "GET /docs/4.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2509
```

I have seen:

- [Bootstrap scrollspy when accessing from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721431/bootstrap-scrollspy-when-accessing-from-another-page) but this is bootstrap 3
- and [Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511045/twitter-bootstrap-scrollspy-not-working-at-all) and this one is some very old version of bootstrap (+6 years ago)

***2.ERROR***

In the original example the navbar area where it send the user is highlighted. Mine not highlighted at all.

***3. ERROR***

The navbar not stay on the top when I scroll or go to any of the navbar elements by clicking on them.

If I implement any of the following than it covers the first few lines of the page.
To keep the navbar above these lines I use `<div class="godown-60" id="godown"></div>` lien of code.

I have tried  class=" ":

```
Fixed navbar 
fixed-top 
sticky-top
```

**base.html**

```
<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="navbar-example2" class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}" > HOME PAGE </a>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
...
```

**home.html**

```
<body>
  <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example2" data-offset="0">
    <h4 id="about">About</h4>
      <a href="{% url 'about' %}">AboutTest</a>
    <p>...</p>
    <h4 id="services">Services</h4>
      <a href="{% url 'services' %}">ServicesTest</a>
    <p>...</p>
    <h4 id="pricing">Pricing</h4>
      <a href="{% url 'pricing' %}">PricingTest</a>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example have solved ERROR 1 and 3 (2 wasn't that important)
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/#

ERROR 1 solution, bey using specified address (these can be actual URL's on the site or libraries as well)

```
href="home/help/#main"
```

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">

  <title>Fixed top navbar example for Bootstrap</title>

  <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/">

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="navbar-top-fixed.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="home/help/#main">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- this solves ERROR 3 -->
  <!-- having a separated section -->
  <main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Navbar example</h1>
      <p class="lead">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how fixed to top navbar works. As you scroll, it will remain fixed to the top of your browser's viewport.</p>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/navbar/" role="button">View navbar docs »</a>
    </div>
  </main>
  <!-- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -->

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
  ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```