# How to make a Twitter Bootstrap 2.x navbar using scrollspy

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, menubar, scrollspy

I would like to make a Bootstrap navbar using the Scrollspy plugin. When I try to use it, the last `<li>` tag always remains active but does not let the the other `<li>` elements go active. If you would like my code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QL99wh2C and here's an image of what I am talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYzg9.png

Answer (score 0):

From your source:

1. add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your document
2. the data-target in your body tag should contain a css selector. In your case `#navbar` or `.navbar` instead of navabar. b.e. `data-target="#navbar"`
3. see this question: [Twitter Bootstrap scrollspy always selecting last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095579/twitter-bootstrap-scrollspy-always-selecting-last-element) so use: `$('body').scrollspy();`
4. 3. gives none selected / active on page load; add class="active" to the first li in your code. Or `$('.nav li:first').addClass('active');` to the bottom of your document.