# Twitter Bootstrap: Scrollspy init using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

The [documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy) says:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">...</body>
```

or

```
$('#navbar').scrollspy();
```

**I'd like to use this second method (js/jquery).**  It seems like you're supposed to call `.scrollspy()` on the nav, and not sure how to specify which element to 'spy' on...  Can't get this to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little digging...

The documentation is wrong.  As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095579/twitter-bootstrap-scrollspy-always-selecting-last-element) points out, you're supposed to use `.scrollspy()` on the content, not the nav.

**But then how do you target the correct nav?**

It turns out, you have to target the parent of the `ul.nav`, and you can pass it to `.scrollspy({target: '.navparent'});` like so.

http://jsfiddle.net/G75m3/2/

Hope this helps someone!