# Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy always highlighting the last element

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out what is going wrong and why only the last section is selected while scrolling.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#homeToolbar" data-offset="50">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="homeToolbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Testing</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#section2">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Product</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section4">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section5">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Below is my code??

Comment: Hey Pranjal, take a look at it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap scrollspy always selecting last element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095579/twitter-bootstrap-scrollspy-always-selecting-last-element)

Comment: Looked at it but didn't resolve my issue

Comment: Post an actual, working example that **recreates** the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[**Check this working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SaurabhSonawane/4ggtd45t/3/)

Try to use the feature of .**affix** with some offset and add **.page-scroll** class to element which going to be scroll.

Your Jquery should be somewhat like this (based upon above fiddle)

```
//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {

// jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)
    }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});

// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
    offset: 51
});

// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a:not(.dropdown-toggle)').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});

// Offset for Main Navigation
$('#mainNav').affix({
    offset: {
        top: 100
    }
});

});
```